# Creating a database from strings available in different Ms Word files in Python

Tags: python

I would like to know If someone can me help me with my problem.
I have several forms (in Ms Word documents, approximately 100). They all have about 20 same questions for each forms and the answers are in strings. I would like to create a data base with all the answers. How would you advice to do this in Python please?

Comment: You could use e.g. https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html to first parse the Word documents. After you have the data parsed out, you could start by writing them out into a JSON file, or a text file, or a pickle, and then follow up by writing to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Shouldn't be too hard to parse those files with that and then export answers to whatever format you want.